# Using a angular template twice and when updating the data binded with on one, it's updating the other.as well

Tags: angular, typescript, model, model-binding

I am using the same angular template twice(once as a popup and second from where the popup is called as the base), and i have a check box input in that which is binded with a boolean property of a model class.

So whenever that is getting updated in the popup, same change is getting reflected at the base template.

How can i keep both the model data separate from each other.

```
<input type="checkbox" style="zoom: 1.3;" value="{model.ID}}"
             [(ngModel)]="model.isSelected" (change)="responseSelection(multipleChoiceOption)" />
      <label>{{model.optionName}}</label>
```

Comment: That shouldn't be. Angular will create a new instance of that Component every time. Do you mind creating a minimal reproducible [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) sample for this?

Comment: @SiddAjmera. Thanks for the quick response.
I was trying to reproduce it, but that's not working.
So i am trying to load checkbox with different data on the pop-up but it's updating the base template as well.

Does angular references to the same model? is it some kind of 2-way binding?

Comment: Try to assign different ids based on the different components, for example [id]="id", where id change based on the components. By the way, don't use the same template for 2 components, i know it looks like you are reusing code but its not the angular way, use couple component even if u need to copy/paste code, also considers use reactive form for all your form/input releated implementation

Comment: Then whats the purpose of creating a template, when we can't reuse it. :(

Comment: As far as I understood the situation you can't do what you want with template because it has the same ngModel. You will need custom form control component for that.

Comment: Okay, thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*same angular template twice* - I guess you are using the same component in html twice??

and the model {ID, isSelected, optionName} object that you are using, if it is the same object on both templates/components, it will update on both places simultaneously.. Please make sure the model objects are different for both templates..

Comment: Hey, can you suggest me any better solution in that case any link? Because not in a state to make a big structural change

Comment: No issues, i fixed the issue with a workaround. anyways Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to suggest a better solution without having a look at the code.. But what I meant in the above was, model_1 = {id: null, isSelected: false, optionName: null} and model_2 = {id: null, isSelected: false, optionName: null} Assign each of these objects to model object of each template respectively.... This is not an Angular specific concept, this is general OOPS concept..